# Changing input path in Batch - path manipulating/modification

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch like this:

```
SETLOCAL
@echo off
SET sourceRoot=d:\SVN\Project\Debug\General\ServicePortal\bin
SET destinationRoute=d:\SVN\Project\Debug\General\Admin Project\
```

I can pass "d:\SVN\Project\Debug\General\Admin Project" through parameter to the bacth, but I don't know how can I cut the last folder "\Admin Project" and combine with "\ServicePortal\bin". Is it possible? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "destinationRoute=d:\SVN\Project\Debug\General\Admin Project"
    for %%a in ("%destinationRoute%\..") do set "sourceRoot=%%~fa\ServicePortal\bin"

    echo %sourceRoot%
```

Get a reference to the parent folder and append the needed elements.

Comment: And if the destinationRoute comes from paramter %1?

Comment: @VajdaEndre, `set "destinationRoute=%~1"`